# Regex find span ids inside parent li tag

Tags: regex

```
<li
data-ttl="1648640"
data-title="text123_Random"
class="item"><span class="slot" id="3673460432">
```

How to extract all Ids which inside li and li has data-title="text123

```
<span[^>]+?id="([^"]+)".*
```

This one extract all spans but i need only thoose which contains data-title="text123

Comment: why are you trying to do this with regex? using DOM will be much better

Comment: Please show an example with DOM

Comment: which programming language are you using? where/how did you this string from?

Comment: vba for Excel please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that RegEx may not be the best way forward, but...

```
<li[^>]*data-title="text123[^"]+"[^>]+><span.*id="([^"]+)">
```

Have fun!

P.S.: Useful RegEx test harness here:

http://powershellprimer.com/html/0014.html#14_2